# *.lib - static or not?

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries

I compile some source files into seperate *.obj modules, then I link them into *.lib static library and link together with another executable. How does Windows OS handles such situations, I mean will it always load whole executable file into memory, or only the parts that are necessary at runtime?

I ask this question, since the profiling programm (code coverage) I use does not cover all the files that it should, so it looks like some parts of the lib file are not in the memory while programm execution.

Answer (score 0):

The executable file is mapped via a file mapping object when it is executed. Therefore, technically only pages of the exe that are actually used will get loaded from disk.

Comment: Is there a way to force my OS to load everything into memory? otherwise the results of code coverage will never be trust-worthy.